# How to sort the data

Tags: android, sorting

i want to sort data if data is[ex:A,a,2,b,B,1,c,3,d,C,4,e,f,5,g,R,h6,i,T,j,7,H]   HERE IN EXAMPLE there are 3 type.  caps alphabetic, small alphabetic, numbers.. and there are "3" checkbox [caps alphabetic, small alphabetic, numbers]. when i check capsalphabeticCHECKBOX ALL RELATED TO caps :A,B,C,R,T,H,a,b,c,d.
which check box i select that order must come first REST must come after that.. How to do it any Idea Please. Currently i am new to ANDROID.Currently i am doing in this way

```
      caps =  (CheckBox) c.findViewById(R.id.capsCheckBox);
    caps .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              sortView.setHint("Sort by Caps");
              if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                  numbers.setChecked(false);
                  small.setChecked(false);
                  caps.setChecked(true);
                  numbersSort = false;
                  smallSort = false;
                  capsSort = true;
                  Collections.sort(ListArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
                      @Override
                      public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                          Sample p1 = (Sample ) o1;
                          Sample p2 = (Sample ) o2;
                          return p1.getPriority().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getPriority());     
                         }
             });
                    dataAdapter = new ListAdapter(ListView.this, ListArray, user);
                    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {                            
                        caps.setChecked(true);  
                    }
          }
        });
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with the way you're doing it? Errors? Bad output? What have you tried to fix it? Be specific, please.

Comment: @Eric smallAlphabet i am geting output in correct way. but  capsAlphabet  geting worng output because i made it reverse & i have output as json proirity .ex: json geting ex:proirity =  "caps" or proirity =  "small" or proirity =  "number". how to do it any idea please

Comment: @Eric i am getting json data in this way "priority":"caps" or "priority":"small" or "priority":"number"  How to sort it.